# Help me understand what mathjax is

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I keep seeing people talk about mathjax on other posts by moderators etc. and it won't let me post/comment on there to ask what it is due to being new and not having enough reputation. So......what is mathjax?

Comment: This belongs on meta.math.stackexchange

Comment: MathJax is the software by which one can write things like $$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x(1-x)} = \infty, $$ coded as \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x(1-x)} = \infty .

Comment: @RossMillikan I couldn't post on there because I am new. Sorry for the inconvenice. I see it got migrated over anyway.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Perhaps the links [in the tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info) and the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) (already posted by Joel) might give you the basic idea.

Answer (score 5):

It is a way to format mathematical things nicely.  It is similar to $\LaTeX$ - I do not understand the differences.  You enclose things in dollar signs and they look nice.  For example if you want the stacked fraction 1/2 you write \frac 12 and put it in dollar signs to get $\frac 12$  You can right click on any MathJax on the site and select Show Math As -> TeX Commands to see how it was done.  That is how I learned the basics.  Web searching covered the finer points.

Comment: It is similar to a small fragment of LaTeX. Most of what LaTeX does is not about mathematical notation, whereas all of what MathJax does is about mathematical notation.

Answer (score 2):

Mathjax is what we use on math.stackexchange.com to format mathematical formulas in a nice and easily-readable way. It is basically LaTeX syntax, with a few minor exceptions. For example, \$x\$ renders as $x$, \$f(x)>15x^2\$ as $f(x)>15x^2$.

You can find a tutorial here: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)